# Security token service exception while restoring snapshot from S3 to AWS managed elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-elasticsearch

I have an AWS managed Elasticsearch Service (say `smallES`) which has an properly working S3 bucket attached to containing day wise rolling indices of last 1 year. I've created another AWS managed ES cluster (say `bigES`) for some business reason. I want to restore last 1 year's data from `bucket` into `bigES`. It's guaranteed that `smallES` `bigES` and `bucket` all are in the same region and same VPC.

So, I created a policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And attached the policy with a role. Trust relationship of that role is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I create a snapshot by http request within the same VPC, it can create a snapshot-repo for the `bigES` and I can query for that too

```
curl -XGET 'http://bigESid.region.es.amazonaws.com:80/_snapshot'
```

Output

```
{
    "snapshot-repo": {
        "type": "s3",
        "settings": {
            "bucket": "bucket",
            "region": "region",
            "role_arn": "role_arn"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to see the snapshots in this snapshot repo I get error (described below)

```
curl -XGET 'http://bigESid.region.es.amazonaws.com:80/_cat/snapshots/snapshot-repo'
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "a_w_s_security_token_service_exception",
                "reason": "User: arn:aws:sts::acountid:assumed-role/cp-sts-grant-role/swift-region-prod-365021432299 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: role-arn (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: some-id)"
            }
        ],
        "type": "a_w_s_security_token_service_exception",
        "reason": "User: arn:aws:sts::acountid:assumed-role/cp-sts-grant-role/swift-region-prod-365021432299 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: role-arn (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: some-id)"
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

I've given all access of s3 to my role, but no luck. I've posted all the http requests from a ec2 machine inside the VPC.

Also to mention, if I query like following, I see expected result

```
curl -XGET 'http://smallESid.region.es.amazonaws.com:80/_cat/snapshots/snapshot-repo'
```

---

IDK why I tried making a role which has trust relationship like following. Still no luck.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
              "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help/suggestions.

Comment: I have something that is similar (a_w_s_security_token_service_exception with ElasticSearch that works for some cluster and not other). Current gut feeling is maybe related to long IDs that is being rolled out. Do you happen to have activated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following policy

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        ]
    }
],
"Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Then I attached the policy to the role. I think `"iam:PassRole"`has done the work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and it was because I'd not allowed the Elasticsearch service to assume the role. I had to update my trust relationship policy document to include `es.amazonaws.com`.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "es.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```